# Attribute error: module 'requests' has no attribute 'Session' in pandas-DataReader

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, pandas-datareader

I am trying to follow [this](https://kylelix7.github.io/Efficient-Frontier-Explained-with-SciPy/) tutorial. However the line:

```py
portfolio = web.DataReader(name=symbol, data_source='quandl', start=start, end=end)
```

is causing errors. After looking at the documentation, I have converted it to:

```py
portfolio = pdr.DataReader(name=symbol, data_source='quandl', start=start, end=end)
```

but I still get the same error:
**AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'Session'**

this is being called from:
"/home/john/.conda/envs/optimizer/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_datareader/_utils.py"

---

Also fails the same as [this](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5329) question. (Question closed with no solution)

#### Recreate

conda install pandas
conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader

```
$ python
>>> import requests
>>> requests.Session()

AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'Session'
```

According to [this](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5329) request, that should work, but it does not. I think the error is with requests, not with pandas-datareader.

---

Edit :: added more information

Comment: What version of requests and pandas_datareader are you using?

Comment: requests-2.23.0  
pandas-datareader: 0.8.1-py_0

Comment: Ah, I think you have a stray file called `requests.py` in your current working directory.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Moved that file and it solved that problem. How did you know that?

Comment: I've seen this problem many times before.

Comment: The filename need not be `requests.py` but can be anything that `requests` imports internally, for example, I faced this issue when I had a file named `socks.py` in my project.

Answer (score 0):

check your spelling.

It should have been `requests.session()` not `requests.Session()`

Comment: No, you are wrong! `requests.Session()` is correct. Have a look at [requests docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects)

Comment: This answer is invalid.